# How to get a count of how many times a value is present in multiple fields

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm building a tracking system where up to three members of the team can be responsible for each item.  I'm trying to build a query to count the number of times that a team member's name ([FullName]) appears in any of the responsible fields ([Responsible],[Responsible2],[Responsible3]).

[image: Example Responsible Table]

So for this example I would like a query that would look in my team table and my responsible table and output something like this.

[image: Desired output]

I've tried

```
SELECT tblTeam.FullName, Count([FullName]=[Responsible] Or [Fullname]=[Responsible2] Or [FullName]=[Responsible3]) AS CountResp
FROM tblTeam, qryItems
GROUP BY tblTeam.FullName;
```

but I'm getting results where people who should have zero values don't, some people who should have positive value have numbers too high, and one person with many responsible instances has a number too low.  Can anyone point me to my rookie mistake here?

Comment: Can you share the wrong result you're getting, and explain how it's wrong?

Comment: You're doing a cartesian join on `tblTeam`, `qryItems` if that's not intentional it would explain the inflated counts

Comment: @FuzzyTree Sorry I'm brand new to SQL.  What is the alternative to a cartesian join and how would I decide when to use it?

Comment: You probably want an inner join. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins

Comment: @FuzzyTree Great post but I don't have a JOIN in my code whereas all of the examples in the post do.  Is JOIN implied in my FROM arguement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach:

```
SELECT FullName, 
SUM(
       (select count(*) from qryItems where Responsible = FullName) + 
       (select count(*) from qryItems where Responsible2 = FullName) +
       (select count(*) from qryItems where Responsible3 = FullName)) 
FROM tblTeam
GROUP BY FullName
```

Comment: I tried this out and got a missing operator when the statement includes the "+" or the "rCounter".  It works fine with what is between "(se...ame)" but attempting to add them in this way doesn't work.  This seems like a good lead to explore.

Comment: Huh. I built my sample in SQL Server and assumed Access would parse the SQL the same.

Comment: Also, @Myles, just so someone has said it, I think your table structure isn't ideal. I would prefer an extra table that's solely responsible for holding responsibilities. So it would have just a ticketID and teamMemberID column and each ticket could appear multiple times with different memberIDs. That would make this counting problem super-simple and also, I suspect, make lots of other things in the future work better.

Comment: I had that but scrapped it because it caused too much complication between initial item entry and automating notification when responsibility changes.  Everything is presently working except this one feature so it's something I will explore again when I start version 1.1.

Comment: The + signs are inside the Sum() declaration?

Answer (score 2):

a simple approach is to union the three columns and then do a group by with a count(*).  Something like the following:

```
select name, count(*) from(
select resp1 as name from table1
union all
select resp2 as name from table1
union all
select resp3 as name from table1)
group by name
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the process, this UNION takes my three fields with X results eachs and makes them into one field with 3*X results then does the comparison.  Is that correct?

Comment: yes that was the idea but union will not work as listed as it does not add dupplicates

Comment: You need UNION ALL to preserve duplicate names.

Comment: that's right! I adjusted the code accordingly and that should produce the desired outcome.  Two issues:  you may want to filter out blanks (add a where clause on each file) and you'll need to produce another file to join to to get names that aren't listed

Comment: Thanks for the effort.  The other answer was more intuitive for me so I worked that angle.